# Designer table relations vs joins

Tags: mysql, join

I just have a small beginners question of MySQL containing relations and joins.

What is the difference between them? In my phpmyadmin in the designer section I can make relationships between tables. So that the tables are linked with each other through for example "id"

But if I in my php code do a join / left join...

for example:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare ("SELECT * FROM visitor 
               LEFT JOIN host ON visitor.host_id=host.id 
               LEFT JOIN reason ON visitor.reason_id=reason.id
               WHERE visitor.id = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $lastid);
$stmt->execute();
```

Isn't that just the same I have done? I am asking now why do you need to set the relations into phpmyadmin? What is the benefit of doing that?

Comment: Just a little tip: PhpMyAdmin is nothing but a graphical client for the MySQL database server (and not a particularly nice one). It's OK to use such tools (we aren't cavemen) but everything's easier if you're always aware of what specific SQL features a given GUI implements. In MySQL, the term "relationship" does not refer to any specific thing. The [screen-shots](http://www.yourwebskills.com/dbphpmyadminrelationships.php) I've found suggest it's a nice form to create **foreign keys**.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, appreciate it! But are there better ways to manage a database other than 'phpmyadmin' then? Mostly i make a .sql file and just import that into 'phpmyadmin' so my database is instantly made and i don't have to do much more than that. Just if i have to make some changes i consult phpmyadmin to run them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you're referring to are foreign keys. You're technically using foreign keys in your join (the reason_id field) already, but by formally defining them it creates an integrity constraint. The advantage of this is that it'd be impossible to accidentally insert a visitor which has an invalid reason_id, it's also possible to specify the delete behaviour to ensure that all related records are cleaned up appropriately. Note that not all storage engines support foreign keys.

See here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Maybe it is hidden into your very good answer but a last question i have is do i have to use JOINS in php if 2 tables are combined with a foreign key?

Comment: Yep, if you want to join them automatically you'll need to create a view based on a query including the join then query that view.